# Android: EditText onclick content

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

My Question is lightweight. I wish to know how do I set a click event inside an EditText also determining which drawable or word is pressed. Basically I have an EditText that can contain word-wrapped drawables or static text.

So I'm expecting something like this:

```
editText.setOnCustomPressListener(new OnCustomPressListener(){
      void onWordTapped(String text){

      }

      void onAttachmentTapped(CharSequence ch){

      }
})
```

Please help, I've been looking for weeks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
mEditText.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
```

It would be good to see more code (your xml)

Comment: I'm not looking for this.. I'm looking for which character or image inside the editText I tapped.

Answer (score 0):

This is not ideal but this is working anyway.

```
    editText.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                int startSelection = editor.getSelectionStart();
                int endSelection = editor.getSelectionEnd();

                String selectedText = editor.getText().toString().substring(startSelection, endSelection);

                AppConfig.quicktoast(selectedText);

            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```